# How to Use Date Picker in Android Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, android-edittext

I have used `Date Picker` in `Activity` but I don't know how to use it in Fragment. I am Uploading my activity `Date Picker` Code. can anyone help me to convert that code in fragment?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();
    context = getApplicationContext();
    View.OnClickListener listenerDate = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    };
    editTextDate.setOnClickListener(listenerDate);
} private void initialize() {
    editTextDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
}private void updateDisplay() {
    currentDate = new StringBuilder().append(day).append(".")
            .append(month + 1).append(".").append(year).toString();
    Log.i("DATE", currentDate);
}
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int j, int k) {
        year = i;
        month = j;
        day = k;
        updateDisplay();
        editTextDate.setText(currentDate);
    }
};`
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you get Any error?

Comment: I have followed the procedure which has given in this link :-   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html But I am getting error -   "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content"

Answer (score 4):

Try this sample:

```
public class YourClass extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showDatePicker();
                }
            });
    }

    private void showDatePicker() {
        DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();
        /**
        * Set Up Current Date Into dialog
        */
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        date.setArguments(args);
        /**
        * Set Call back to capture selected date
        */
        date.setCallBack(ondate);
        date.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
    }

    OnDateSetListener ondate = new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

            edittext.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)
               + "-" + String.valueOf(year));
        }
    };            
}
```

Now create class DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    OnDateSetListener ondateSet;
    private int year, month, day;

    public DatePickerFragment() {}

    public void setCallBack(OnDateSetListener ondate) {
        ondateSet = ondate;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        super.setArguments(args);
        year = args.getInt("year");
        month = args.getInt("month");
        day = args.getInt("day");
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), ondateSet, year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rahul. I am getting Date Picker Dialog when i click on Edit Text but i think editText.setText is not working.. I am not getting the selected date to the Edit Text. can you help me to set date. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your fragment:

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance() //global

public void showDatePickerDialog(){

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    datePickerDialog.show();
}


DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateYourLabel(); // or whatever you want
    }

};
```